# How to Run Java3D on Window10 with Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 Card(DirectX), using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, opengl, applet, directx, java-3d

I could not load a 3D object using Java3D 1.5.1. I tried a few examples like:

(1) HelloUniverse.java from [https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs324e/CodeSamples/HelloUniverse.java](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Escottm/cs324e/CodeSamples/HelloUniverse.java)
The major error for this and other Java 3D Applications is "no J3D in java.library.path" like this screenshot
[Errors with Java3D Applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cFEE.png)
I have put "j3dcore-ogl.dll" in C:\Window and other system folders, but when I run "regsvr32 j3dcore-ogl.dll", I got 'The module "j3dcore-ogl.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.' I tried but failed to find an OpenGL driver for my Graphic Card. I tried but failed to switch to the DirectX option as documented in the "Java3D/1.5.1/README.html".

(2) Mykeynavbeh.java (Toy Plane) from https://sites.google.com/site/java3dapplets/home/source-code-toyplane
The major error from this and other Java 3D Applets is "Could not find or load main class sun.applet.AppletViewer" like this screenshot
[Errors with Java3D Applets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYMxC.png)
I changed my JRM to JavaSE-8 but has no effect. The author, Mykeynavbeh or fukinotou11d (his username here and on Youtube Channel) seems have been running these applets and application with a PC successfully. I really wish someone like him could help me out. Thank you all in advance. Perry

Comment: Observe that Java applets (and Java3D apps) are obsolete nowadays.  Can you explain why you want to run such programs?

Comment: Hi Peter O. Thank you for the comments.  The reason is I do not know other options.  Java is the only language I have played with. I should have said I am open for other suggestions but I don't believe I can learn a new language quickly.  Someone recommended PyOpengGL, but I don't know if PyOpenGL will still depend on OpenGL, which I do not have for my Graphic Card.  What would you suggest for a retired guy like me just want to load and manipulate 3D, like a .obj object on my PC?

Comment: Questions like that which seek opinions or recommendations are off topic for this site. Try searching this site for other 3D programming technologies, some of which require little more than a Web browser.

Comment: Please rather use Java3D 1.6 or 1.7 provided by the JogAmp community. I remind you that Java3D 1.5 is totally obsolete and applet support was removed from Java and from many web browsers for years, you may have to rewrite those examples to make them work without using applets. By the way, please install an OpenGL driver as Java3D will use OpenGL under the hood anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[1] Is j3dcore-ogl.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdkx.x.x\jre\bin? (For the 64-bit version, Program Files)

Please check

- j3dcore-d3d.dll
- j3dcore-ogl.dll
- j3dcore-ogl-cg.dll
- j3dcore-ogl-chk.dll

are in the above bin folder,

and

- j3dcore.jar
- j3dutils.jar
- vecmath.jar

are in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdkx.x.x\jre\lib\ext

If the required files are in the correct directories, I think Java3D programs should work fine using Java3D 1.5.1 in Java8.

If they are not in the above folders, probably something wrong with the installer for Java 3D (for the 64-bit installer, sometimes one of the required .dlls was missing), or you didn't reinstall Java3D after the new JDK is installed, for example after updating JDK from 1.7 to 1.8.

If you can't find these files in the above folders, try the following manually:

1. Copy these .dll files from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java3D\x.x.x\bin
   to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdkx.x.x\jre\bin.
2. Copy these .jar files from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java3D\x.x.x\lib\ext to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdkx.x.x\jre\lib\ext.

Please install (copy) the above files while watching my video,

"How to Put a MetasequoiaLE(Free) Model into Java 3D_2," 1:34
https://youtu.be/AXhPFOupwUM

because their locations are a little hard to find.

[2] You may want to use Java3D 1.6. Java3D 1.5.1 is no longer maintained. On the other hand, Java3D 1.6 is actively maintained by devoted developers. Native libraries (.dll) are wrapped up in jogamp-fat.jar, so you don't have to worry about .dll files.

[3] https://sites.google.com/site/java3dapplets/home/source-code-toyplane

This program is a java application extending the Applet class, and not an applet to be executed in an AppletViewer or on a web browser. It can be executed as an ordinary java program as it is in Java8, and can be distributed as a .jar file.

I used to display applets in that website. The site name "Java3D Applets" comes from this. Sorry for the confusion and misleading. I removed those applets because they could not be used any more, and instead started posting there simple Java 3D application source code. Google notified that starting September 1, 2021, the Classic Google Sites would no longer be viewable, so I moved the contents of the old site to the new site, and rearranged the site:

https://sites.google.com/view/flying-java-3d/home